# why is awk printing only first word in a field?

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I have a tabulated `.txt` file with three fields, the third field often having multiple words:

```
GO:0000002  Akt3    mitochondrial genome maintenance
GO:0000002  Mef2a   mitochondrial genome maintenance
GO:0000002  Mgme1   mitochondrial genome maintenance
GO:0000002  Mpv17   mitochondrial genome maintenance
GO:0000002  Mrpl15  mitochondrial genome maintenance
```

I wanted to swap fields 1 and 2 using `awk`, but when i run the command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $2,$1,$3;}' file.txt
```

I get:

```
Akt3    GO:0000002  mitochondrial
Mef2a   GO:0000002  mitochondrial
Mgme1   GO:0000002  mitochondrial
Mpv17   GO:0000002  mitochondrial
```

Why do i not get all the words in the third field, and how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to solve the problem, but the main issue is that the output field separator has been set, but the default input field separator is both tabs & space. Setting them both to tab should give the output you want (or make it more generalizable by just swapping the first two fields & printing the remainder of the line)

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"; FS="\t";} {print $2,$1,$3;}' file.txt
```

Comment: Oh right! this solution is easier to understand for me, thanks!

Comment: awk can chain the variable assignments: `FS = OFS = "\t"`

Comment: @glennjackman absolutely (as the other answer already demonstrated), but I kept them separate in case the OP wanted them to be different values, showing how multiple statements could be made in `begin{...}`

Answer (score 3):

You are printing 3 fields, that is why you only get 3 fields in the output. You are setting `OFS` to a tab but not `FS`.

What you can do is flip only field 1 and field 2 using a variable like `f1` to hold the field 1 value while switching the values.

Then print the whole line adding `1` after the closing parenthesis to print the whole line. In case you have more columns you don't have to  manually specify them when printing.

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
{f1 = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = f1;}1
' file.txt
```

Output

```
Akt3    GO:0000002      mitochondrial genome maintenance
Mef2a   GO:0000002      mitochondrial genome maintenance
Mgme1   GO:0000002      mitochondrial genome maintenance
Mpv17   GO:0000002      mitochondrial genome maintenance
Mrpl15  GO:0000002      mitochondrial genome maintenance
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution works! Regarding field 3, it has several space separated words, so shouldnt it be printed as a whole?

Comment: @ForEverNewbie Are there tabs or spaces between `GO:0000002  Akt3    mitochondrial` ?

Comment: There are tabs between `GO:0000002  Akt3    mitochondrial`, and spaces between `mitochondrial genome maintenance`

Comment: @Thefourthbird : lemme mention this trick i discovered - u can swap 2 variables in a single statement like this  : `$2 = $1 substr( "" , $1 = $2 )` : it doesn't lead to a race condition at all. In fact, you can even swap between completely unrelated data types (including swaping btwn array cells; just not the entire array), and they wouldn't be re-casted into another type inadvertently.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Thank you for your comment, you have a  lot of tricks op your sleeve :-) So this sets the value of $2 to the value of $1 concatenated with an empty string. Then in the substr you switch $1 to $2 right?

Comment: @Thefourthbird : yeah … and because it's an empty string, the concat operation isn't performed at all, so numeric types actually stay numeric instead of becoming whatever format `CONVFMT` was at that moment. I even used `gawk` in unicode mode to try swapping between purely binary data of an mp3 file with random variables, and it managed to get the identical mp3 file back out, as confirmed by hashing. But you can't do both swaps inside the same call, like `substr("", $2 = $1 , $1 = $2 )` <<< this doesn't work at all. i only discovered this trick about 2-3 months ago.

Comment: @Thefourthbird : so one prominent example would be `Fibonacci sequence` : you can emulate the typical `python` code `a, b = b, a + b` with `b = (a + b) substr("", a = b)` in `awk`. In fact, you can even streamline that to just `b += a substr("", a = b )`